# My response seems to hang in response class while working with sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I am currently implementing a web proxy but i have run into a problem.I can parse my request from the browser and make a new request quite alright but i seem to have a problem with response.It keeps hanging inside my response loop

```
    serveroutput.write(request.getFullRequest());
            //  serveroutput.newLine();
                serveroutput.flush();
                //serveroutput.
                 //serveroutput.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Writting tothe server was unsuccesful");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Write was succesful...");
             System.out.println("flushed.");

             try {
                 System.out.println("Getting a response...");
                 response= new    HttpResponse(serversocket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("tried to read response from server but failed");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

              System.out.println("Response was succesfull");



      //response code

        public HttpResponse(InputStream input) {
    busy=true;

      reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
      try {
          while (!reader.ready());//wait for initialization.

          String line;
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              fullResponse += "\r\n" + line;


          }

          reader.close();
          fullResponse = "\r\n" + fullResponse.trim() + "\r\n\r\n";
      } catch (IOException`` e) {

          e.printStackTrace();
      } 
      busy = false;
  }
```

Comment: Does the server send a "new line" at the end of it's response?  `reader.readLine()`...From the Java Docs *"A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed"*  Also - you probably won't need `reader.ready()` as the `reader.readLine()` will block until it has read a line from the buffer any way...IMHO

Comment: I really cant tell what the browser sends till i parse the whole response

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a blocking, synchronous read on a socket. Web servers don't close their connections after sending you a page (if HTTP/1.1 is specified) so it's going to sit there and block until the webserver times out the connection. To do this properly you would need to be looking for the `Content-Length` header and reading the appropriate amount of data when it gets to the body.

You really shouldn't be trying to re-invent the wheel and instead be using either the core Java provided `HttpURLConnection` or the Appache `HttpClient` to make your requests.

Comment: I am just designing a proxy and wanted to learn the nuts and bolts of socket programming.

Comment: Well, there you go :) You'll have to correctly handle the HTTP protocol if that's the case or ... it'll hang for the reason I state above.

Comment: Can you please point me in a direction or give me a few steps to follow .

Answer (score 1):

```
while (!reader.ready());
```

This line goes into an infinite loop, thrashing the CPU until the stream is available for read. Generally not a good idea.

Comment: My problem is actually in the read line section.It seems to hang in there.

Comment: @user1850254 Nevertheless you should remove this pointless line.

Answer (score 1):

You are making numerous mistakes here.

- Using a spin loop calling `ready()` instead of just blocking in the subsequent read.
- Using a `Reader` when you don't know that the data is text.
- Not implementing the HTTP 1.1 protocol even slightly.

Instead of reviewing your code I suggest you review the [HTTP 1.1 RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html). All you need to do to implement a naive proxy for HTTP 1.1 is the following:

1. Read one line from the client. This should be a CONNECT command naming the host you are to connect to. Read this with a DataInputStream, not a BufferedReader, and yes I know it's deprecated.
2. Connect to the target. If that succeeded, send an HTTP 200 back to the client. If it didn't, send whatever HTTP status is appropriate and close the client.
3. If you succeeded at (2), start two threads, one to copy all the data from the client to the target, as bytes, and the other to do the opposite.
4. When you get EOS reading one of those sockes, call `shutdownOutput()` on the other one.
5. If `shutdownOutput()` hasn't already been called on the input socket of this thread, just exit the thread.
6. If it has been called already, close both sockets and exit the thread.

Note that you *don't* have to parse anything except the CONNECT command; you don't have to worry about Content-length; you just have to transfer bytes and then EOS correctly.

Comment: If i may ask you  a quick question.What do you mean by using reader when you don't know if the data is text

Comment: I mean *don't use a `Reader` unless you know the data is text.* The body of an HTTP request can be anything at all. Use an `InputStream.`